# How to clone a directory from GitHub to a different location on my desktop?

Tags: git

I try to clone like this,

```
git clone https://github.com/angularjs-in-action/angello-lite.git
```

by issuing the above command from cmd in Windows

By default, a directory(***angello-lite***) inside the git folder is created inside

```
C:\Program Files\Git
```

Since I don't have permission to create it being a office machine,

[image]

Any suggestions on how to create to a different location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set the clone destination

```
git clone https://github.com/angularjs-in-action/angello-lite.git c:\yourPath\yourSubPath
```

Comment: Beautifull. Thanks a lot. I will accept within a few mins your answer.

Answer (score 2):

By default, git clones into the present working directory. Normally people just change directory in their shell and then clone from there.

Comment: Thanks a lot for further explaining it.

Comment: @msrd0 It absolutely answers the question. The nod to Daniel's answer is an aside.

Comment: Shouldn’t this rightly be just a comment instead of an answer? (Somebody flagged it as low-quality and it’s in the Low Quality Posts review queue.)

Comment: Vote as you will, but I still think it is the answer to the question.

Comment: Looks OK to me. I edited to (hopefully) make that more obvious.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just go to the directory where you have write access and then clone the repo. Something like:

```
cd C:\my-projects\
git clone https://github.com/angularjs-in-action/angello-lite.git
```

By default git tries to clone in the current directory (and the project files are created under a subdirectory inside the current folder). You actually start in the *C:\Program Files\Git* folder because the shell executable is there and the prompt opens there.